# Joining Objects in Blender breaks my model

Tags: modeling

I do not know what to do. Every combination of join breaks my model. I have tried separating each object and making them single user but to no avail.

[image: Before Join]

[image: After Join]
[image: Details and objects]

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your curves to Mesh Before you join them

To do that, select your curves and go to Object menu > Convert > Mesh

[image]

Comment: Joining the objects worked, but when exporting as an fbx file, and importing it to unreal engine, my textures were all messed up.

Comment: Possibly: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures